# Stripe API (PHP) - Create a charge with default payment method card

Tags: php, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I am using Strip PHP API and trying to create a charge:

```php
$chargeData = [
    "amount" => $amountTaxed,
    "currency" => $this->settings->currency_code,
    "source" => 'tok_visa', // Card token
    //'customer' => $this->user->stripe_id,
    "description" => __('general.add_funds') . ' (Auto-recharge) @' . $this->user->username,
    'metadata' => [
        'user' => $this->user->stripe_id,
        'amount' => $amountTaxed,
        'taxes' => $this->settings->tax_on_wallet ? $this->user->taxesPayable() : null,
        'type' => 'deposit'
    ]
];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create($chargeData);
```

Below is payment method card detail added in customer account

[image]

I know how to get card token via card number

```php
$token = \Stripe\Token::create([
    'card' => [
        'number' => '4242424242424242',
        'exp_month' => 7,
        'exp_year' => 2024,
        'cvc' => '314',
    ],
]);
```

If I get token manually using the card number `\Stripe\Token::create`, stripe's charge method `\Stripe\Charge::create` works fine. So my only problem is to get the source/token.

**My intention is to get the token from existing payment method's card.**

If there is any other way to charge from customer's existing payment methods's card, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an older integration path. Stripe's Charges API still work but are not recommended. I recommend starting with [their guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment) for building an integration that charges a customer and saves their payment details for later charges.

Comment: You saved my day @LauraT. I was scratching my head since morning. Haha. 

Below is the code I am using now and it's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution with the help of @LauraT.

```php
$paymentIntent = PaymentIntent::create([
    'amount' => $amountTaxed, // Amount in cents (e.g., $10.00)
    'currency' => $this->settings->currency_code,
    'customer' => $this->user->stripe_id, // Replace with the customer ID in Stripe
    'payment_method' => $default_payment_method_id, // Replace with the payment method ID (Visa card) in Stripe
    'confirm' => true, // Set to true to confirm the payment immediately
]);
```